# UnmarshalException: unexpected element on XML just been Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I get an UnmarshalException (unexpected element) when unmarshallering XML, which i have just run through marshaller. I looks like the marshalling process generates XML, which cannot be unmarshalled.

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
EjendomSoegType type = objectFactory.createEjendomSoegType();
EjendomSoegningKriterierType krit = new EjendomSoegningKriterierType();
{
    krit.setBy("Skovlunde");
}
type.setEjendomSoegningKriterier(krit);
JAXBElement<EjendomSoegType> soeg = objectFactory.createEjendomSoeg(type);

// create JAXBContext which will be used to update writer
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(EjendomSoegType.class);

// marshall or convert jaxbElement containing element to xml format
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(soeg, writer);

String xml = writer.toString();
System.out.println( xml );

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
soeg = (JAXBElement<EjendomSoegType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

The following UnmarshalException is thrown by the last line of the code  *unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader)*:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/", local:"EjendomSoeg"). Expected elements are (none)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:609)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:244)
```

The generated XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns8:EjendomSoeg xmlns:ns2="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/model/1/" 
        xmlns:ns4="http://rep.oio.dk/cpr.dk/xml/schemas/core/2005/03/18/" 
        xmlns:ns3="http://rep.oio.dk/kms.dk/xml/schemas/2005/03/11/" 
        xmlns:ns5="http://rep.oio.dk/bbr.dk/xml/schemas/2005/03/11/" 
        xmlns:ns6="http://rep.oio.dk/bbr.dk/xml/schemas/2005/12/15/" 
        xmlns:ns7="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/elektroniskakt/1/" 
        xmlns:ns8="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/">
    <ns7:EjendomSoegningKriterier>
        <By>Skovlunde</By>
    </ns7:EjendomSoegningKriterier>
</ns8:EjendomSoeg>
```

Why is the UnmarshalException thrown?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION ADDED LATER: The createEjendomSoeg method in ObjectFactory has the @XmlElementDecl tag.

```
/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EjendomSoegType }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/", name = "EjendomSoeg")
public JAXBElement<EjendomSoegType> createEjendomSoeg(EjendomSoegType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<EjendomSoegType>(_EjendomSoeg_QNAME, EjendomSoegType.class, null, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@XmlElementDecl` annotations on the `ObjectFactory` are not being picked up.  To have `ObjectFactory` processesed you need to create the `JAXBContext` on this class, or on the package of your generated model.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
```

If there isn't an `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` corresponding to the element you are trying to unmarshal then you will need to use an `unmarshal` method that takes a `Class` parameter.

```
soeg = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader), EjendomSoegType.class);
```

Comment: I do not know the XElementDecl annotation - can you point to me where i can find something about XElementDecl annotation. The ObjectFactory has the XmlRegistry annotation. The whole stuff is generate from WSDL with the 'Web Service Client' builder in NetBeans.

Comment: @LarsLadegaard - I wrote the following article about `@XmlElementDecl`.

Comment: For me it looks like i am using an unmarshaller based on a Class parameter, as context is created with JAXBContext.newInstance(EjendomSoegType.class) using a EjendomSoegType.class as input, wherefrom the unmarshaller is created: context.createUnmarshaller().

Comment: The createEjendomSoeg method in ObjectFactory has the @XmlElementDecl tag.

Comment: @LarsLadegaard - Were you able to try creating your `JAXBContext` by passing in the `ObjectFactory` class as the parameter?

Comment: It is working now :) I did not do exactly as you said in your answer (second line of code). I have done that now and it is working - thanks :)